# Extra bottom margin with reledpar

Tags: margins, reledmac, reledpar, bottom

I'm using the `reledpar` package to have one chapter of a book with two texts typeset in parallel on pairs of facing pages (no footnotes or critical apparatus).

Unfortunately, that chapter exhibits an extra bottom margin compared to the other chapters, as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Normal}
\lipsum[1-24]

\numberlinefalse
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledchapter{Reledpar left}
\pend
\pstart
\lipsum[1-12]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledchapter{Reledpar right}
\pend
\pstart
\lipsum[1-12]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Please note that the removing the `geometry` package does not solve the issue.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks!

Comment: If I load `reledpar` with either one of the options described in §2.1 of the manual, `shiftedpstarts` and `advancedshiftedpstarts`, there is still some whitespace at the bottom, but it gets much better. Not a complete solution, but might help you in a pinch :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, the problem with those options is that they seem to disable the syncing of the chunks...

Comment: You should set `setgoalfraction`. See § 6.2.4 of reledpar handbook about that point

Comment: @Giuseppe: Did you try Maïeul's suggestion? Let us know if that helped, so that an answer can be written and the question can be marked as solved, for future reference :-)

Comment: @marquinho: I tried Maïeul's suggestion, and indeed it helps to mitigate the problem (indeed I voted the comment as useful), while still some noticeable extra margin remains.